# Can't scrape some elements off of zillow website

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape content of the zillow website.

Ex- https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/689-Luis-Munoz-Marin-Blvd-APT-508-Jersey-City-NJ-07310/108625724_zpid/

The problem is I can't scrape contents of the price and tax history.
I thought that they are javascript elements loading when the page loads and hence tried using selenium but i still can't get them. 
Following is what I tried.

Code

```
phistory = soup.find("div",{"id": "hdp-price-history"})
print phistory
```

Html

```
<div class="loading yui3-widget yui3-async-block yui3-complaintstable yui3-hdppricehistory yui3-hdppricehistory-content" id="hdp-price-history">
  div class="zsg-content-section zsg-loading-spinner_lg"></div>
</div>
```

This is the outermost element but doesn't have any elements inside.Also tried `soup.find_all("table",class_ = "zsg-table yui3-toggle-content-minimized")` which yields none.

Comment: Can you post the scraper code?

Comment: Relevant code is included above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to wait until required `<table>` generated and became visible:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/689-Luis-Munoz-Marin-Blvd-APT-508-Jersey-City-NJ-07310/108625724_zpid/")
table = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="hdp-price-history"]//table')))
print(table.text)
```

Output:

```
DATE EVENT PRICE $/SQFT SOURCE
05/03/17 Listed for sale $750,000+159% $534 KELLER WILLIAM...
06/15/11 Sold $290,000-38.3% $206 Public Record
10/14/05 Sold $470,000 $334 Public Record
```

You can also parse it without using `BeautifulSoup`, e.g.

```
print(table.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[text()="Listed for sale"]/following::span').text)
```

Output:

```
$750,000
```

or

```
print(table.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[text()="Sold"]/following::span').text)
```

Output:

```
$290,000
```

Comment: I am trying to use the same technique here [link](https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1102-Woodland-Ave-Pittsburgh-PA-15212/11498396_zpid/) but it doesn't seem to work. I also tried using id and element. Following is what i tried
 `wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
table = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//section[@id="yui_3_18_1_2_1494945298474_1290"]//table')))`

Comment: `id` of `section` is dynamic (it changes each time you refresh the page), so you cannot use it in `XPath`. Try `//h2[text()="Price History"]/following-sibling::table`

Comment: I tried `table = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.XPATH, "//h3[text()='Price History']/following-sibling::table")))

print table.text`

It still doesn't fetch anything.

Comment: Element in my `XPath` is `h2` while it is `h3` in yours. Edit and try again

Comment: yes, the heading there was h3. I tried both h2 and h3.

Comment: So `wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//h2[text()="Price History"]/following-sibling::table'))).text` returns you an excpeption, right? Could you double check as it works well from my side...

Comment: Yea, it wasn't returning anything. Not entirely sure why that happened, but I had got it using beautiful soup.